# How to solve SKSpriteNode bug on screen?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4

I am working on a game in which there are fish nodes which descend from the top of your screen. These fish are initialized with a custom class and are moved with a SKAction.moveTo() please see the code below.

The issue I am having is that my fish position randomly increases in Y value for a single frame and then return to their intended position. It may be hard to see in the photos but it is easily visible while playing. Even though my moveAction moves the fish down the screen the second picture shows the fish higher than it was in the first picture.

[SEE FRAME 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqVLD.jpg)
[SEE FRAME 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzZ3w.jpg)

I call my setupFish() function in the update method where I run a timer that shortens as you collect fish nodes and increase score.
I am not sure this code has anything to do with the issue I'm having but it gives you a better idea of how I put the fish in the game.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
            if nextEnemyAddTime <= currentTime {
            priorEnemyAddTime = currentTime
                if gamePlaying == true {
                setupFish()
                }
        }
    }



private var priorEnemyAddTime: CFTimeInterval = 0



 private var nextEnemyAddTime: CFTimeInterval {

        let waitTime = score < 50 ? Double.random(in: 1.3...2.3)
            : score < 100 ? Double.random(in: 1.2...2.1)
            : score < 250 ? Double.random(in: 1.1...1.9)
            : score < 500 ? Double.random(in: 1.0...1.7)
            : score < 1000 ? Double.random(in: 0.9...1.5)
            : score < 2500 ? Double.random(in: 0.8...1.3)
            : score < 5000 ? Double.random(in: 0.7...1.1)
            : score < 10000 ? Double.random(in: 0.6...0.9)
            : score < 50000 ? Double.random(in: 0.4...0.7)
            : 0.3
        return priorEnemyAddTime + waitTime
    }
```

Here is my custom class of Fish

```
import SpriteKit

enum FishType: String {
    case redFish, purpleFish, orangeFish
}

class Fish: SKSpriteNode {

    let type: FishType

    init(type: FishType) {
        self.type = type
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "fish")
         super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Here is the function I use to add the fish nodes.

```
func getNewFish(type: FishType) -> Fish {

            let fish = Fish(type: type)

            fish.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.fish
            fish.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero
            fish.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none

        return fish
    }

        func setupFish() {
            let fish = self.getNewFish(type: self.getFishType())
            let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: frame.maxX*0.25...frame.maxX*0.75), y: frame.maxY + fish.size.height/2)
            fish.zPosition = 1
            fish.name = "fish"
            fish.size = CGSize(width: ((fish.texture?.size().width)!)/14, height: (fish.texture?.size().height)!/14)
            fish.position = randomPosition
            fish.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "fish")
            fish.zPosition = 1
            addChild(fish)
            let randomDouble = Double.random(in: 0.5...1.2)
            let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: randomPosition.x, y: frame.minY), duration: gameSpeed*randomDouble)
            fish.run(moveAction) {
                fish.removeFromParent()
                fish.removeAllActions()
                self.streak = 0
            }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where dies the new fish get it’s physics body from? I know this (probably) isn’t the cause of the issue though.

Comment: I give my fish their physics bodies in the func getNewFish(type: FishType) -> Fish. In a separate file I declare the different Physics Categories that I want the characters to have.

import CoreGraphics                                               

struct PhysicsCategory {
    
    static let none: UInt32 = 0
    static let enemy: UInt32 = 0x1
    static let hero: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let fish: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let all : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    
}

Comment: - I can't see anything in the 'Fish' class or your `getNewFish` function that allocated a physics body, so I was wondering if there is some code we're not seeing? I can;t see this `import CoreGraphics struct PhysicsCategory...`

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry about that I was tinkering with the code right before I posted this and deleted the part where I gave the physics body its shape and size. I made it a circle of radius that is fish.size.height/2 right before I declare its Bitmasks